# XSLT Error - element not declared

Tags: xslt

I need to transform the following xml

```
<node1 xmlns:ns1="namespace1">
  <node2 xmlns:ns2="namespace2">
    <node3...>
    <node4...>
  </node2>
</node1>
```

To

```
<NewNode2 xmlns:ns2="namespace2">
  <node3...>
  <node4...>
</NewNode2>
```

I use this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:ns1="namespace1"
                xmlns:ns2="namespace2">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <NewNode2>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//*[local-name()='node2']" />
    </NewNode2 >
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this throws error in visual studio - 
*input validation error - element 'namespace1:node1' not declared
and element 'namespace2:node2' not declared*

Comment: Why does your subject say "XSLT error" when you get an "input validation error"?

Comment: Please provide exact copy-paste versions of files that demonstrate the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info. After I correct the errors in the imprecise versions you've provided, I cannot reproduce your error mesage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal van be achieved with the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:ns1="namespace1"  
   xmlns:ns2="namespace2"
   xmlns="namespace2">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
       <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:node1">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns2:node2">
       <ns2:NewNode2>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
       </ns2:NewNode2>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The statement `<xsl-templates select="/" />` inside `<xsl:stylesheet match="/">` causes an infinite loop, since the matching template for the called 'root' is the template itself, which is calling the root.

The template `<xsl template match="@*|*>` belongs in almost all stylesheets, because this copies the content of all elements which are not otherwise specified (most applicable selection rule).

The other two templates specify specific behaviour for ns1:node1 (do not output any information at this level, but continue the template matching process for all further levels) and for ns2:node2 (create ns2:NewNode2 and continue to include all other availble information inside).